# 'sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch, sql

(I know this isn't really meant for here, but I can't ask questios on Stack Exchange)

I'm creating a batch file and I get this error message:
'sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

I know why my code is wrong but don't know how to fix it.. I haven't got MYSQL and I'm not using Microsoft SQL server 2005, I'm using SQLyog and there is no sqlcmd, so what do I change my code to?

This is my code:

```
@echo off
cls

set /p SName=Server Name :
set /p UName=User Name : root
set /p Pwd=Password :
set /p DbName=Database Name : test

set /p choice=ARE YOU SURE TO EXECUTE SCRIPTS in %DbName% (y/n) ?

if '%choice%'=='y' goto begin
goto end

:begin
if exist _dataimport.txt del _dataimport.txt

@echo on

sqlcmd -S %SName% -U %UName% -P %Pwd% -d %DbName% -I -i "UDDs"\UDDs.sql >> _dataimport.txt 2>&1



@notepad _dataimport.txt


:end
```

Comment: I'm confused,  you say "I haven't got MYSQL"-- Yet "SQLyog is the most powerful MySQL manager and admin tool, combining the features of MySQL Administrator, phpMyAdmin and other MySQL Front Ends and MySQL GUI tools."  Why/how are you using SQLyog if you're not using MySQL?

Comment: I mean the MYSQL program, sorry my bad

Comment: Huh? MySQL is a database. SQLyog is a MySQL admin/editor tool.  You need access to a MySQL server for SQLyog to be useful. If you have a working MySQL server, then you should have SQLCmd available to you. If MySQL is installed on your local machine, it probably exists but just isn't in the path.  Have you searched your HDD for SQLCmd?

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything with MySQL when installed, and I have and to no avail. (this is the search on my HDD)

Comment: "I don't recall seeing anything with MySQL when installed" so did you install MySQL, or not? If so, what version did you install? The poin tis oyu need a copy of MySQL's `sqlcmd.exe`.  If it wasn't included in your install, you can probably get it from the MySQL site.

Comment: No.. I downloaded SQLyog version 11.11 at the instructions of my employer and that was that but I'll give your idea a try and keep you updated :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Huzzah! I installed the SQLCMD from microsoft and it's now running smoothly, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have properly installed your SQL softwares, if the command prompt returns with:

> (*name of the software*) is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

this means that your software is not probably placed into the folder defined by the `%PATH%` environment variable. With this latter it is possible to recall executable applications without defining their full path.
Then, to solve this issue you can:

1. define the full path to the `.exe` file in you batch script
2. or move the `.exe` file into the directory defined by `%PATH%`

You can see the list of the directories defined by this environment variable invoking the `set` command from the terminal or opening `Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables`